# Prove $(a+ba)^*ba = (a^*ba)^+$ and $(a+b(ab)^*aa)^* b(ab)^*a = (a^*ba)^+$

Tags: linear-algebra, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm 100% sure that both these regular expressions are same since it produces an exactly same set of strings, but I'm unable to prove it mathematically. Can someone please provide me with a step by step solution of the prove?
**Prove:**
`1)(a+ba)*ba = (a*ba)^+`
`2)(a+b(ab)*aa)*.b(ab)*a = (a*ba)^+`
I tried using these identities:
`RR* = R*R   R*R* = R*   (R*)* = R*   RR* = R*R   (PQ)*P =P(QP)*   (a+b)* = (a*b*)* = (a*+b*)* = (a+b*)* =a*(ba*)*`

Comment: What dialect of regular expression you are using? It seems your '+' stand for union (i.e 'a+b' means either 'a' or 'b'). Is your 'X^+' standards for XX* where * is the Kleene closure and what is your '.'  ?

Comment: Yes you're correct : 1)here 'a+b' stands for either 'a' or 'b'  2)here  'X^+' stands for kleene plus.

Comment: 3) for '.' I mean ab =a.b

Comment: '.' is normal multiplication. It is NOT a metacharacter.

Comment: @achillehui  check it out^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules we are going to use. I hope I didn't miss anything.

1. $(P+Q)^* = P^*(QP^*)^*$.
2. $(PQ)^*P =P(QP)^*$.
3. $P^* = \varepsilon+P^+$.
4. $P^+ = P^*P = PP^*$.
5. $PQ + PR = P(Q+R)$ and $PQ + RQ = (P+R)Q$.
6. $\varepsilon P = P = P \varepsilon$.

Let $c = ba$.

For the first identity,  we have:

$$(a+ba)^{*}ba = (a+c)^*c \stackrel{(1)}{=} a^*(ca^*)^*c \stackrel{(2)}{=} (a^*c)^*a^*c \stackrel{(4)}{=} (a^*c)^{+} = (a^*ba)^{+}$$

For the second identity, notice 
$$b(ab)^*a \stackrel{(2)}{=}(ba)^*ba = c^*c \stackrel{(4)}{=} c^{+}$$
we have

$$\begin{align}(a+b(ab)^*aa)^*b(ab)^*a 
&= (a+c^{+}a)^*c^{+}\\
&\stackrel{(6)}{=} (\varepsilon a + c^{+} a)^*c^{+}
\stackrel{(5)}{=} ((\varepsilon+c^{+})a)^*c^{+}\\
&\stackrel{(3,4)}{=} (c^*a)^*c^* c\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=} c^*(ac^*)^*c
\stackrel{(1)}{=} (a+c)^*c
\stackrel{(1)}{=} a^*(ca^*)^*c\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}(a^*c)^*a^* c
\stackrel{(4)}{=} (a^*c)^{+}\\
&= (a^*ba)^+
\end{align}$$

Comment: Simply perfect, Thanks a ton! (Also can you please upvote my question so that I've enough reputation to ask another questions too).I can't even upvote your answer because of less reputation.